# Can someone learn English by listening?

Tags: listening, memorization

I have learning English through English grammar. Still it would be improved but damn I have not learned or comprehend! never and never I no understood by listening! only  I can understand  words or sentences I know  that come easily to my brain. --easy to understand.

I have to try and work to make sentences all the time, but the problem is that I feel that information is discharged from my brain every day. I remember some small parts of it forcefully. (Bu cümlelere hâla uzağım)(I just got a little help with this.)

In order to learn vocabulary by listening, I have to memorize the sound structure. I feel sorry about this and it is not happening.

Let me say a different country, I do not like to say foreign. I will look stupid, stupid for not understanding when I stay.

So I set my goal. I made my decision I will learn I will learn even if there is no teacher. I'm just forgeting all the information when I force my brain to write a sentence for a certain minute. Because he is not registered at the office!

Although there are similar old structures in English in my own language, it turns into a chaos when it is constantly added to the end in today's Turkish.

My questions are
What is the way to memorize the sound structures of words in speech without subtitles on TV. I compensate for these by working one by one words.

Do english native speakers understand every word spoken? Or is someone just taking it out of the sentence?

Comment: Do you read? There needs to be a coordinated approach to learning English. You have to read, speak, write, listen, and think. Do you understand things when you read? Often non-native speakers think that they need to start reading a newspaper to improve their English or comprehension skills. That is a bad starting point for a learner. Start by reading something very simple, something that you enjoy. What about comics? Can you read and understand them?

Comment: Yes I  understood  largely, My trouble is I can't memorize words by watching a TV series. As one by one  words!  I don't do firstly this way is  they need to start reading a newspaper to improve their English or comprehension skills. Maybe, after 
What about comics? Fifty and Fifty

Comment: I do a guess exercise on listenaminute.com It is helpful

Comment: Writing what you have heard or read can be a helpful aid to the learning process. Listen to something, then write it down.

Comment: You can watch movies and TV series and documentaries with Closed Captions turned on.....

Comment: I would like to recommend closed captions, but they are frequently awful. I think comic books, comic strips, graphic novels would be a great place to start. From there, you could go to classic children's books like Peter Pan, Wind in the Willows, and so on. If you find something you like, read it and re-read it. Native speakers do this a lot especially when they are young.

Comment: Comic books. They are a good start. They help a lot as you can take your own time to read them word by word. Close captioning can be helpful later on in your learning curve.

Comment: Yes, yes.
I would like to express my sincere thanks to   every one of you.
I will try to memorize. The words will need to listen to 40 expeditions.
I'll let you know the developments after 1 month.

Answer (score 1):

When native English speakers learn English for the first time, they do it by listening and speaking, since they're too young to read. So it can be done!

That being said, you have the advantage of being able to read. It takes children several years to understand and create meaningful sentences but if you're really dedicated you could get to that point in less than a year.

Use your ability to read to your advantage. Start by watching a movie in English with English subtitles on, then watch it again with the subtitles off. You'll be familiar with the basic plot and you'll be able to make more sense out of the audio than you would have otherwise.

You can also watch simpler media. Depending on your comfort level, you can even watch media intended to teach kids English! Again, watch it with or without subtitles depending on where you're at in your understanding of it.

At the end of the day, don't feel bad if you don't understand 100% of what you hear. I'm sure you don't understand 100% of what you hear in your native language, and I don't in mine (and mine happens to be English). I still often rely on subtitles in movies or looking up lyrics in music I listen to in order to fully understand it.